# Django Rest Framework Read Only Model Serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I want to have a total read only `ModelSerializer`, i.e. just list/retrieve methods

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is that what you want or do you want to remove the create/update from the view sets ?

Comment: good point @Linovia, actually im looking for [ReadOnlyModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset)

Answer (score 45):

You really want to do this at the view (or Viewset) level, which you can do with a [ReadOnlyModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset).

(You mentioned this in your comment but I'm leaving it as an answer for better visibility).

For example (from the documentation):

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets


class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

Answer (score 29):

If you do need a serializer to be read only, it's most concise and stable option to override the **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    setattr(self.Meta, 'read_only_fields', [*self.fields])
```

In comparison with the above:

- @mgalgs's solution is best, if a view irrespective of the serializer used should be read only.
- @thisisms solution is best if you only have a few and non-dynamic fields
- @D W's approach will only work if there are no writable serializer fields that use the 'source' keyword.

---

**EDIT better solution:**
You can update the def get_fields method instead of the init method and create an abstract serializer:

```
class ReadOnlyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super().get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in fields:
            fields[field].read_only = True
        return fields
```

To use it, just inherit from the abstract serializer:

```
def MySerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: This is a great solution which doesn't use any private fields, and is extensible - if you have a lot of read-only serializers, this could be used in a base class.

Comment: @tbm indeed, I edited my answer to include an alternative solution using an abstract serializer class.

Answer (score 17):

The only thing you have to do is create a serializer like this.
serializers.py

```
class YourdataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Yourdata
        # some data
        fields = ('id', 'city', 'pincode', 'created')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'city', 'pincode', 'created')
```

Views something like this

```
class YourdataList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        yourdata = YourdataList.objects.all()
        serializer = YourdataSerializer(yourdata, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

detail view

```
class YourdataDetail(APIView):
   def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Yourdata.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Yourdata.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = YourdataSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This will do it.

Comment: One way to make this a little more streamlined is to have `read_only_fields = fields` in `Meta`.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a `ModelSerializer` you can achieve this with the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("field_1", "field_2", etc)
        read_only_fields = [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]
```

This solution uses the private `_meta` interface of the django model, but it's fairly stable and it's used fairly extensively by developers.

Here we're simply generating a list of all the fields in the relevant model and applying it to the `read_only_fields` option from `django-rest-framework`.

I prefer doing this at the serializer level as opposed to the view level as it doesn't tie you down to using Viewset's as suggested by [mgalgs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599266).

If you wanted to take this a step further, you could even wrap the functionality into a mixin which adds to the `Meta` options of your class. Something such as:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import Field


class ReadOnlyMixin(Field):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        setattr(
            cls.Meta,
            "read_only_fields",
            [f.name for f in cls.Meta.model._meta.get_fields()],
        )
        return super(ReadOnlyMixin, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class MyModelSerializer(ReadOnlyMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ("field_1", "field_2", etc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok dear Mohsen,To implement a read-only serializer using the BaseSerializer class, we just need to override the .to_representation()method. Let's take a look at an example using a simple Django model:

```
class HighScore(models.Model): 
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
 player_name=models.CharField(max_length=10) 
 score = models.IntegerField()
```

It's simple to create a read-only serializer for converting HighScore instances into primitive data types.

```
class HighScoreSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
 def to_representation(self, obj): 
  return { 'score': obj.score,  'player_name': obj.player_name }
```

Comment: look at my comment on my own post. 
thank you Hamed,

Comment: Thats depend on view but your answer was about read only serializers

Comment: I was initially looking for a solution in Serializer level, but its more natural to handle it in view level, and there is ReadOnlyModelViewSet for that

Answer (score 1):

two solutions for this?

```
from rest_framework.utils import model_meta

class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        model = getattr(self.Meta, 'model')
        declared_fields = copy.deepcopy(self._declared_fields)
        info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)
        field_names = self.get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        _, hidden_fields = self.get_uniqueness_extra_kwargs(
        field_names, declared_fields, extra_kwargs)
        fields_names.extend(hidden_fields.keys())
        setattr(self.Meta, 'read_only_fields', list(field_names))
```

or

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        setattr(self.Meta, 'read_only_fields', list(self.fields))
```

Comment: `read_only_fields = fields` this also works if fields is not '__all__'